# jQuery как проверить содержимое элемента на пустую строку

Tags: jquery

jQuery как проверить содержимое элемента на пустую строку

```
<div>
  <p>
    <span class="concretisize_uslug">Текст</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="concretisize_uslug"> </span>
  </p>
</div>
Если в элементе пустая строка не показывать его вместе с родителем
if (".concretisize_uslug").text()==""){
    $(this).parent().css("display","none");
}
```

Это не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.concretisize_uslug').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().trim() === '')
      $(this).parent('p').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>
    <span class="concretisize_uslug">Текст</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span class="concretisize_uslug"> </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.